# Output RFC 3339 Timestamp in Java

Tags: java, timestamp, rfc3339

I want to output a timestamp with a PST offset (e.g., 2008-11-13T13:23:30-08:00). `java.util.SimpleDateFormat` does not seem to output timezone offsets in the *hour:minute* format, it excludes the colon. Is there a simple way to get that timestamp in Java?

```
// I want 2008-11-13T12:23:30-08:00
String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'h:m:ssZ").format(new Date());
System.out.println(timestamp); 
// prints "2008-11-13T12:23:30-0800" See the difference?
```

Also, `SimpleDateFormat` cannot properly parse the example above. It throws a `ParseException`.

```
// Throws a ParseException
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'h:m:ssZ").parse("2008-11-13T13:23:30-08:00")
```

Comment: For new readers to this question I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Use `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. See [the answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68428268/5772882).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Starting in Java 7, there's the `X` pattern string for ISO8601 time zone. For strings in the format you describe, use `XXX`. [See the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone).

Sample:

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")
        .format(new Date()));
```

Result:

```
2014-03-31T14:11:29+02:00
```

Comment: I am getting ParseException while parsing "2017-12-12T02:01:43.924-08:00" which I got from Google Cloud APIs

Comment: @pujanjain That has milliseconds, which this pattern does not include.

Comment: I'd argue that any answer which claims to be RFC3339-compliant must address the optional 1-digit millisecond as per https://xml2rfc.tools.ietf.org/public/rfc/html/rfc3339.html#anchor14

Answer (score 20):

Check out the [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) package.  They make RFC 3339 date formatting a lot easier.

**Joda Example:**

```java
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2011,1,2,12,45,0,0, DateTimeZone.UTC);
DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
String outRfc = fmt.print(dt);
```

Comment: This answer would actually be useful with an example.

Comment: @Biff You can simplify your code example. No need for formatter. Joda-Time automatically defaults to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) / [RFC 3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) format. Just call the `toString` method, either explicitly or implicitly. Like this, `String output = dt.toString();`

Answer (score 16):

I spent quite a lot of time looking for an answer to the same issue and I found something here : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Suggested answer:

`String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'h:m:ssZZZZZ").format(new Date());`

If you notice I am using 5 'Z' instead of one. This gives the output with a colon in the offset like this: "2008-11-13T12:23:30-08:00".  Hope it  helps.

Comment: Thanks - your answer is underrated - this is what finally allowed me to output RFC 3339. Using X gave me `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern component: XXX
 at org.apache.commons.lang.time.FastDateFormat.parsePattern(FastDateFormat.java:691)
 at org.apache.commons.lang.time.FastDateFormat.init(FastDateFormat.java:558)`

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 14):

From the "get it done dept," one solution is to use regexes to fix up the string after SimpleDateFormat has completed.  Something like s/(\d{2})(\d{2})$/$1:$2/ in Perl.

If you are even remotely interested in this, I will edit this response with the working Java code.

But, yeah.  I am hitting this problem too.  RFC3339, I'm looking at you!

EDIT:

This works for me

```
// As a private class member
private SimpleDateFormat rfc3339 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

String toRFC3339(Date d)
{
   return rfc3339.format(d).replaceAll("(\\d\\d)(\\d\\d)$", "$1:$2");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that Z produces the time zone offset without a colon (:) as the separator.

Comment: Absolutely correct, but doesn't tell us how to fix it. The solution from jjohn fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

We can simply use [ZonedDateTime class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) and [DateTimeFormatter class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for this.

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxx");
ZonedDateTime z2 = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println("format =======> " + z2.format(format));
```

Output: format =======> 2024-01-30T15:00:07-05:00

Answer (score 3):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'h:m:ss.SZ");
```

Is not what exactly you need?

Comment: No. If you try to parse the timestamp given above, it will throw ParseException.

Answer (score 2):

i tried this format and worked for me `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'`

Answer (score 1):

I found a stray PasteBin that helped me out with the issue: http://pastebin.com/y3TCAikc

Just in case its contents later get deleted:

```
// I want 2008-11-13T12:23:30-08:00
String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'h:m:ssZ").format(new Date());
System.out.println(timestamp); 
// prints "2008-11-13T12:23:30-0800" See the difference?

// Throws a ParseException
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'h:m:ssZ").parse("2008-11-13T13:23:30-08:00")

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'h:m:ss.SZ");
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a [InternetDateFormat](http://mericleclerin.blogspot.jp/2013/07/internetdateformat-for-rfc3339.html) class for RFC3339.

But source code comment is Japanese.

PS:I created English edition and refactoring a little.

Answer (score 0):

I tested a lot with this one, works well for me... In particular when it comes to parsing (and for formatting too), it is the closest I have found so far

```
DateTimeFormatter rfc3339Formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;

DateTimeFormatter rfc3339Parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .parseCaseInsensitive()
    .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4)
    .appendLiteral('-')
    .appendValue(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2)
    .appendLiteral('-')
    .appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)
    .appendLiteral('T')
    .appendValue(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
    .appendLiteral(':')
    .appendValue(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
    .appendLiteral(':')
    .appendValue(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
    .optionalStart()
    .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 2, 9, true) //2nd parameter: 2 for JRE (8, 11 LTS), 1 for JRE (17 LTS)
    .optionalEnd()
    .appendOffset("+HH:MM","Z")
    .toFormatter()
    .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)
    .withChronology(IsoChronology.INSTANCE);
```

Test cases at https://github.com/guyplusplus/RFC3339-DateTimeFormatter

Comment: It’s correct and it’s using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, which is good. We don’t need this complication. See the answers by Vijay Upadhyay and Arvind Kumar Avinash.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Actually after rechecking DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME is the best.

Comment: This is not entirely correct, that is it won't parse valid RFC3339 values that have 1 digit in the fractional second. Actually, RFC3339 allows any number of digits in the fraction, but Java time only supports up to 9 (even in lenient mode). Therefor I think it should be `appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 0, 9, true)`

Comment: Actually it does parse 1 digit in the fractional second, tested on line 95. There is a bug in JDK up to 11, where it needs to be 1 or 2 (c.f. line 38) in `appendFraction` depending on JDK version.

If setting second parameter to 0 for `appendFraction`, date-time such as "1985-04-12T23:20:50.Z" (line 140) is considered valid, but it is not according to RFC3339: if there is a period, at least 1 digit is required. Ok it gets super detailed there!

As for max 9 digits, yes it is JAVA limitation.

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:** The largest city in the [Pacific Time Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Time_Zone) is Los Angeles whose timezone name is *America/Los_Angeles*. Using `ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")`, you can create an instance of  `ZonedDateTime` which has been designed to adjust the timezone offset automatically on [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) transitions.

If you need timezone offset but not the timezone name, you can convert a `ZonedDateTime` into `OffsetDateTime` using [`ZonedDateTime#toOffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toOffsetDateTime--). Some other uses of `OffsetDateTime` are to create a Date-Time instance with a fixed timezone offset (e.g. `Instant.now().atOffset(ZoneOffset.of("+05:30"))`, and to parse a Date-Time string with timezone offset.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoneId zoneIdLosAngeles = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
        ZonedDateTime zdtNowLosAngeles = ZonedDateTime.now(zoneIdLosAngeles);
        System.out.println(zdtNowLosAngeles);

        // With zone offset but without time zone name
        OffsetDateTime odtNowLosAngeles = zdtNowLosAngeles.toOffsetDateTime();
        System.out.println(odtNowLosAngeles);

        // Truncated up to seconds
        odtNowLosAngeles = odtNowLosAngeles.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println(odtNowLosAngeles);

        // ################ A winter date-time ################
        ZonedDateTime zdtLosAngelesWinter = ZonedDateTime
                .of(LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2021, 11, 20), LocalTime.of(10, 20)), zoneIdLosAngeles);
        System.out.println(zdtLosAngelesWinter); // 2021-11-20T10:20-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
        System.out.println(zdtLosAngelesWinter.toOffsetDateTime()); // 2021-11-20T10:20-08:00

        // ################ Parsing a date-time string with zone offset ################
        String strDateTime = "2008-11-13T13:23:30-08:00";
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime);
        System.out.println(odt); // 2008-11-13T13:23:30-08:00
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
2021-07-18T03:27:15.578028-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]
2021-07-18T03:27:15.578028-07:00
2021-07-18T03:27:15-07:00
2021-11-20T10:20-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
2021-11-20T10:20-08:00
2008-11-13T13:23:30-08:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/LOGLlN)

You must have noticed that I have not used a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse the Date-Time string of your question. It is because your Date-Time string is compliant with ISO-8601 standards. The modern Date-Time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards.

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using Google Library

```
new com.google.api.client.util.DateTime(new Date()).toStringRfc3339()
```