# Date serialization Google Cloud Endpoint

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore

I save a Entitiy with a new() date in java.util.Date type, on Google DataStore, and then I got it to the Android Client, and I get it in this format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'
```

> example: '2015-12-27T09:49:51.013Z'

I save the date on shared preferences in Android client in string with this method:

> .getDate().toStringRfc3339()

Then later, when I need send it to the server, I try to set the date of the entity in this way:

```
.setDate(stringDateInServerFormatToDate(date));

public com.google.api.client.util.DateTime stringDateInServerFormatToDate(String dateInServerFormat){  
                googleDate = new com.google.api.client.util.DateTime(dateInServerFormat);

        return googleDate;
    }
```

And that works, but when I try put it on the server by Endpoints, I get this error:

> "message":
>   "com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException:
>   Can not construct instance of int from String value
>   '2015-12-27T09:49:51.013Z': not a valid Integer value\n at [Source:
>   N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain:
>   com.imaginamos.caapturesupervisor.backend.Entities.User[\"userUpdate\"])"

I have tried many fromas and have not been successful. 
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the Endpoints API that you're talking to expects the timestamp to be a simple integer, like seconds or milliseconds. It depends on how the Cloud Endpoints API declared the timestamp field in the Bean class.

If it used `com.google.api.server.spi.types.DateAndTime`, it should accept the RFC3339 string that you're passing. (The same may be true for `java.util.Date`, though I've never tried it.) For example:

```
import com.google.api.server.spi.types.DateAndTime;

public class ExampleBean {
  private DateAndTime timestamp = null;

  public DateAndTime getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
  }
  public void setTimestamp(DateAndTime timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
  }
}
```

When building with a Bean like that, the REST JSON discovery doc advertises the field as a date-time string, which means it should accept an RFC3339 string as its value:

```
"timestamp": {
  "type": "string",
  "format": "date-time"
}
```

`DateAndTime` is pretty dumb, just a wrapper for the string. When working with it, I immediately turn it into a Joda DateTime:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
...
DateTime timestamp = new DateTime(
    exampleBean.getTimestamp().toRfc3339String(),
    DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

But, if the Endpoints API declared the field as an `int` or `long`, it won't know how to convert your RFC3339 string into a number, and you would need to send the number directly.

If you have access to the code of the Endpoints project, try taking a look. Or, see if the API Explorer works for you, at `https://PROJECT_APP_ID.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer`; it should help you figure out the expected field type.

Comment: Hi @dbort I am developing de Endpoint too, Do you work with com.google.api.server.spi.types.DateAndTime? can you show me examples with that type, of implementation in server and client, for parsing it, thx!

Comment: I added more info to my answer; take a look and let me know if it help!

Comment: Thanks, I will more late if works for me, then I will accept the answers

Comment: I tray set a date: DateAndTime now = DateAndTime.parseRfc3339String(new DateTime().toString()); but server say "message": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DateAndTime string is not valid RFC3339: Mon Jan 04 00:53:10 UTC 2016"

Comment: In your example, what's the fully-qualified type of `DateTime`? Its `.toString()` is producing "Mon Jan 04 00:53:10 UTC 2016" which is not RFC3339.

I'm using JodaTime (org.joda.time.DateTime) which, in my experience, produces RFC3339 strings; [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289311/output-rfc-3339-timestamp-in-java#comment34703009_289927) agrees, but maybe things are different in your environment.

Comment: is org.joda.time.DateTime

Comment: Maybe your environment is different from mine. You could try using an explicit date formatter like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/289927/150001 (`ISODateTimeFormat`)