# How can I store String type DateTime string to ISO DateTime Format in MongoDB in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am receiving a string format DateTime Strings data from the android app.
according to the previous developer's note, it's RFC 3339 format string.

I am stuck in converting this string into MongoDB's Date format in Node.js
in detail edit documents, formats are like below.

[ current string what I receive    ->    Date format in MongoDB, which I wanna store]
[    "2020-09-14 08:18:56",        ->        ISODate("2020-09-14T08:42:41.000Z")    ]

Is there any way to save those strings into MongoDB on NodeJS programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RFC 3339 is a profile (a set of standards derived) of ISO 6081 (see these SO posts: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522251/whats-the-difference-between-iso-8601-and-rfc-3339-date-formats), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369287/what-pattern-should-be-used-to-parse-rfc-3339-datetime-strings-in-java)), so you can just pass the string to `Date`'s constructor and get a valid js `Date`:

```js
var raw = "2020-09-14 08:18:56";
var date = new Date(raw);
console.log(date);
```

Comment: I literally add few hours as correction to the original time string and converted the way you mentioned above.thanks for the advice :)