# Convert Timestamp from db and Timezone column into RFC 3999 format

Tags: java, postgresql

Before I'll start - I've looked at those answers and didn't got the required answer:

- [Output RFC 3339 Timestamp in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289311/output-rfc-3339-timestamp-in-java)
- [Convert OffsetDateTime to UTC Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651210/convert-offsetdatetime-to-utc-timestamp)

I've currently read from a database 2 column:

- created_at (a timestamp in which this column was created - for example, `2016-12-23 15:39:15`)
- timezone - the timezone of the timestamp (for example - `GMT+01:00`).

I need to convert this information into an `RFC 3999` (e.g. - `2019-10-02 10:19:23-0800` representation of the time. however, I cannot figure out how to do so since from what I've saw `OffsetDateTime` expect a different format for the Timezone.

Another option might be to do it on the database level - but I couldn't figure out a way to do this as well...

**EDIT:**

If you have both the local time and the timezone you can use `ZonedDateTime` as follow:

```
final date = new LocalDateTime(...);
final String timezone = ...;
ZonedDateTime.of(date, ZoneOffset.of(zone));
```

Comment: Which column types are in database? `CHAR`, `VARCHAR` ?

Comment: `created_at` is a timestamp and `timezone` is varchar

Comment: Ok, I've got it.
Actually I hope there's chance to refactor database to make one column with `timestamp with time zone` type

Comment: Unfortunately not, this dB doesn’t owned by me, I’m only allowed to read from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
    ResultSet rs = ...;
    LocalDateTime createdAt = rs.getObject("created_at", LocalDateTime.class);
    String timezoneStr = rs.getString("timezone");

    String createdAtRfc3999 = convert(createdAt, timezoneStr);
...
}

private static final DateTimeFormatter IN_ZONE_OFFSET_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("O");
private static final DateTimeFormatter RFC3999_DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");

public static String convert(LocalDateTime datetime, String strOffset) {
    ZoneOffset zoneOffset = IN_ZONE_OFFSET_FORMATTER.parse(strOffset, ZoneOffset::from);
    return datetime.atOffset(zoneOffset).format(RFC3999_DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
}
```

There's shouldn't be a problem to get `created_at` as LocalDateTime instance from the database whether via pure JDBC or via JPA

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for a simple type cast:

```
SELECT CAST (
          CAST (
             '2016-12-23 15:39:15' || ' ' || 'GMT+01:00'
             AS timestamp with time zone
          )
          AS text
       );

          text          
------------------------
 2016-12-23 17:39:15+01
(1 row)
```

Comment: In general, it looks good, my main concern is how will this impact performance since I'm executing my query on a huge dataset that continues to grow in almost 1.5M rows each day

Comment: That is rather cheap, four C function calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in SQL:

```
select to_char(created_at at time zone timezone, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss TZH:TZM')
from the_table
```

This assumes that `timezone` contains a valid time zone representation that is accepted by Postgres.